# make: *** No rule to make target '%.o', needed by 'Program.exe'. Stop

Tags: gnu-make

i have my source files inside the src folder and when i run make (windows) i get the following error
make: *** No rule to make target '%.o', needed by 'Program.exe'.  Stop.

```
VPATH := src

Program.exe : %.o
    g++.exe -o bin/program.exe  $<


%.o : %.cpp
    echo $<
    g++ -c -ILibraries/include -LLibraries/lib $< -lgdi32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` in make is not a wildcard that matches files.  Just as well, because when make starts there won't be any `.o` files to match.

The `%` in make is a pattern match and it only works in pattern rules: pattern rules must have a `%` in the *target* (like the second rule you have, `%.o : %.c`).  If you don't have a `%` in the target, then make just thinks that the `%` in the prerequisite list is a normal character like an `a` or `b` or whatever.  Make doesn't know how to create a file named, literally, `%.o` because there is no matching `%.cpp` file.

Also it's always wrong in make to create a file that is not equal to `$@`.  Here your target is `Program.exe` but your recipe creates a file `bin/program.exe`: those are not the same thing so it's wrong.

Also `$<` is only the FIRST prerequisite: when you want to link lots of files together you want to use `$^` which is all the prerequisites.

You need to list all the object files you want to create:

```
bin/program.exe: src/foo.o src/bar.o src/baz.o
        g++.exe -o $@ $^
```

If you want to automatically generate all the object files then, assuming you want to compile all the source files, you can do something like:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard src/*.cpp))

bin/program.exe: $(OBJS)
        g++.exe -o $@ $^
```

You don't need to set VPATH in this situation; it doesn't help.